# hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac not found on AWS CentOS instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hashlib

I am running a Python application on a standard AWS CentOS instance. When the code tries to call hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac it raises an AttributeError exception. The code is as below:

```
import hashlib, binascii

hashed_password = binascii.hexlify(hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(result.encryption_method, bytearray(password.encode('utf_32')), binascii.a2b_uu(result.salt), result.encryption_rounds))
```

I have run `yum update` in the hopes of updating Python 2.7 to the latest version, but this hasn't helped. Any help on how to get hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pbkdf2_hmac was only just added to hashlib in Python 2.7.8 as part of [PEP 466](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0466/).

I suggest installing the python-passlib package instead and using [passlib](https://pythonhosted.org/passlib/index.html) as CentOS doesn't have Python 2.7.8.

Comment: I will check out passlib. Thanks for the tip!